# Android NDK C #ifndef problems

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I am using the NDK-r6 on Windows and want to compile a simple **C** program for testing purposes.
Just compiling a **C** console program is not this easy, but I got the needed options.
The command line I use is (in cygwin):

```
 /cygdrive/f/android/android-ndk-r6/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
-fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -D__ARM_ARCH_5__
-D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te
-mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb -Os  -funroll-all-loops -fomit-frame-pointer
-fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -IF:/android_ws/stkeys/jni -DANDROID  
-Wa,--noexecstack -O3 -DNDEBUG -g -Wl,
-rpath-link=/android/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib 
-L/android/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib -nostdlib
/android/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o 
-lc -IF:/android/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include
F:/android_ws/stkeys/jni/stkeys.c F:/android_ws/stkeys/jni/sha1.c
-o F:/android_ws/stkeys/jni/stkeys
```

One hell of a commandline, but it works. The problem is, that this code breaks:

```
#ifndef uint32_t
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
#endif

#ifndef uint8_t
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
#endif
```

This are the errors:

```
In file included from F:/android_ws/stkeys/jni/stkeys.c:44:
F:/android_ws/stkeys/jni/sha1.h:23: error: redefinition of typedef 'uint32_t'
F:/android/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/stdint.h:53:
note: previous declaration of 'uint32_t' was here
F:/android_ws/stkeys/jni/sha1.h:27: error: redefinition of typedef 'uint8_t'
F:/android/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/stdint.h:49:
note: previous declaration of 'uint8_t' was here
```

I got it to compile by commenting out the definitions of uint32_t etc. in stdint.h, but this can't be the solution.
Is this a bug in the NDK, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: this is the path where I have the code. It is not really jni code. There are just the stkeys.c sha1.c and sha1.h files in there

Answer (score 2):

It obviously isn't expecting stdint.h to be included. Don't know why.

The test `#ifndef` only works for testing if something has been `#define`d. There is no way to do `typedef`s conditionally.

I would rather hack the application code than the standard headers. :-)